# What is Difference B/w dispose and Finalize Method in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I found many article and forms that define the difference b/w finalize and dispose method but still now i have one doubts that is.
Doubt  : we know that at run time destructor    of class convert into finalize method. What will happen if we doesn't define a destructor in Class. I mean till now destructor will convert into finalize or not?  . How Memory Management will perform now.

Comment: "we know that at run time destructor of class convert into finalize method" - do you have any links explaining that? (Since it happens at compile time I don't think you can find one...)

Comment: Since you saying you've seen many articles already (probably including suggested duplicate), can you also clarify what exactly you trying to understand? Maybe small class like `class MyClass{ public int Data {get;set;}}` without destructor and explanation what you expect/don't expect to happen with such class?

Answer (score 1):

A `Dispose` method is present on classes that implement `IDisposable` (I guess you could have one without the interface, but it would be less useful). In such a method you should clean up any un-managed resources you have. It also:

1. Lets you put a `using` block around your object so the framework will invoke `Dispose` for you.
2. Lets users know they should probably call `Dispose` before letting the object fall out of scope.

A *finalizer* (which happens to look like a C++ destructor) is called by the garbage collector... eventually. Given the lack of control you have over when it is invoked, you should be very careful about relying on them. Not having one is no trouble at all (and the vast majority, almost all really, of classes do not need them). Additionally, you *definitely* don't need one if you implement `IDisposable` as unmanaged resources should already have been released (and `GC.SuppressFinalize` called) before the finalizer would run.

Comment: Typically, a class that implements `IDisposable` has no use at all for a destructor. It's always recommended to call `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` on disposing so the garbage collector does not attempt to call the finalizer (and possibly release resources that had already been released)

Comment: @MatiCicero Thanks, Included that.